# AV CLI Scanner for Linux

Tags: linux, security, anti-virus

I need an Anti Virus CLI Scanner for a standalone server (without internet access). OS is RHEL 7, but it must be able to scan windows file systems (for a windows viruses). I'm using a ClamAV, but I need some additional scanner.

Requirements:

1. RHEL 7 OS
2. CLI
3. Ability to download definitions on another computer and copying them
   to a standalone server
4. Scanning for a windows viruses
5. Small size (possibly without a gui)

Comment: What is it about ClamAV that doesn't work?

Comment: ClamAV is great. It's exactly what I need. But there is requirement for additional scanner (double scan)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest to use FPROT it works fine and it's compliant with all of them!

Comment: I've tried it. One thing - you can't download definitions from the web site or ftp. And I'm not sure, if you can simply copy definitions files from one computer to another.. Maybe you have such experience?

Comment: 50 01 * * * nice -n5 /opt/f-prot/fpupdate > /dev/null 
This is in my crontab and makes regular update , I don't know if you have to pay just few money, but it works for all my mailserver perfect and don't take a lot of resource like clamav.
Clamav don't scale up for real mail server and take huge resources when you have high traffic and many mailbox... believe me!:-)

Comment: The question is, if I can run an update command on computer A, and then just copy definitions to another computer B?

Comment: Personally I don't understand why, you can use a proxy server in this case, with a large cache in order to reduce the traffic and have more speed if you need to update a large infrastructure. 
Otherwise I have been checked and it makes antivir.def in the main dir with rsync maybe you can do that, and probably works.

Comment: My problem is not a traffic. We have a closed standalone network, so I can't connect it to the internet.

Comment: Ok , in some scenario it's possible that , I think of course it works if you use rsync you will safe to have exaclty the same file it will be like a red-hat satelite model .. don't forget to accpet my answer in case!! :-)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. I'll try it. ( I won't forget :) )